# create partition on behalf of table owner

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I am looking for the way of creation new partitions in PostgreSQL DB from the user who doesn’t own the parent table.
However, I am constantly facing “ERROR: must be owner of table”
I tried such approach:

1. Direct creation of partition from current user to user who owns the table – mentioned ERROR ☹
2. Create stored procedure on table owner schema – grant execution on procedure to another user (from which I want to create a partition) – attempt to call the procedure (from user who should create the partition) and same ERROR ☹

So what is the correct approach to solve my challenge.

PS. I am from Oracle world and just started discovery of PostgreSQL Permission model. So may be I am missing smth in privileges.

Comment: The second approach should work if you used `SECURITY DEFINER` on the procedure. Otherwise doing something via a function call doesn't change permissions.

Comment: @Bergi, Yeap! That was this small thing that I was looking for! please put your comment as an answer and I will accept it!
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create stored procedure on table owner schema

This approach should work.

> grant execution on procedure to another user

That's not enough. Just doing something via a function call doesn't affect the permission checks, they're still applied to the current role. What you need for a procedure to affect permission is set the [`SECURITY DEFINER` option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). (Check the [tips](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) for doing it properly).